# How to solve 'Oracle JDK 8 is NOT installed.' error, even though I have installed it before?

Tags: apt, software-installation, ppa

I have Java on my Ubuntu 16.04 system, but every time I try to install a program / package I get an error:

```
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Setting up oracle-java8-installer (8u131-1~webupd8~2) ...
Using wget settings from /var/cache/oracle-jdk8-installer/wgetrc
Downloading Oracle Java 8...
--2017-08-14 19:20:07--  http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/8u131-b11/d54c1d3a095b4ff2b6607d096fa80163/jdk-8u131-linux-x64.tar.gz
Resolving download.oracle.com (download.oracle.com)... 188.43.76.48, 188.43.76.74
Connecting to download.oracle.com (download.oracle.com)|188.43.76.48|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 403 Forbidden
2017-08-14 19:20:08 ERROR 403: Forbidden.

download failed
Oracle JDK 8 is NOT installed.
dpkg: error processing package oracle-java8-installer (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 oracle-java8-installer
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: How do you know you have installed Oracle Java 8? How did you install it? The installer from webupd8's java PPA doesn't think you have...

Comment: @zanna I downloaded it from a site and installed it using terminal and even i set home variables, then made it the default Java on system, also javac 1.8.0_141 command returns  '' javac 1.8.0_141 and
java version "1.8.0_141"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_141-b15)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.141-b15, mixed mode)
but ubuntu cannot know it!

Answer (score 2):

If you installed Java by a different method, and you are happy with your Java setup, then remove the webupda8 PPA that is causing errors:

```
sudo add-apt-repository -r ppa:webupd8team/java
```

Then run

```
sudo apt update
```

Answer (score 2):

Thanks, after searching on Internet i solved my problem:

1. I removed 'ppa:webupda8team/java' apt repository in **software and
   update**(press--> Superuser key-->type in the search 'software and
   update'-->'other software' tab-->remove the 'ppa:webupda8team/java'
   from list
2. then i checked the source.list file to remove if any 'ppa:webupda8team/java' is exist using:

   `sudo nano /etc/apt/source.list`
3. i also checked the source.list.d directory for removing java ppa file using :

   `sudo rm -i /etc/apt/source.list.d/webupda8team`
4. then i update the repository using :

   `sudo apt-get update`